# Add object to Autocomplete Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm using Jquery autocomplete field. To be clear here's a documentation -> http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Now I want to add element to this field by jquery script. Why ? I have ajax form which inserts entity to base and after closing this ajax form I want to append / inject / add (I'm not sure which word is the best to say this) to this autocomplete field. I want this element to be already chosen, not append to the list by RenderItem.
I have this object serialized in json - I'm guessing this is the right format because in Token Input field this format was necessary to make something simillar.

Thanks for any tips and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit source using `$.data()` function

```
var ac = $( "#autocomplete" );
ac.autocomplete({
    source: [ "c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby" ]
});
var data = ac.data('uiAutocomplete');
data.options.source.push('python');
ac.data('uiAutocomplete', data);
```

About "already chosen":

```
ac.val('python');
```

Comment: Lol... It was so obvious and I was looking for some strange workarounds... I didn't think that autocomplete is initialized just on field which is text type and I can simple change it's value... Heh... thanks for help ;-)